# Modifying CSS based on user-defined settings

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on a web-based text editor and want to be able to offer the user a host of settings -- font size, background color, etc. I am saving the content of the editor in `LocalStorage`, so I was thinking of storing a `settings` object in the same place and automatically applying the settings when the page loads, is that the right way to go about it?

My second question is: once I have the values of teh settings that they have input, what is the best way to modify the CSS to reflect these changes? I've poked around Less but haven't been able to find a solution. What is the best way to change the appearance within a javascript function?

Thanks!

Comment: local storage will only persist for a single browser. it would be better to have a database to store this information. that being said local storage will work for users that use the same browser / device. To update the values you need to use inline styles in javascript to update with user preferences

Comment: You can also set style tags. If you have a limited set of options you can set classes with predefined styles. I know that duckduckgo use these 2 methods: https://duckduckgo.com/settings